# Avd showing old version of my application

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

So i've make some change's in my app (it was about nesting layouts - My root layout, was linear layout,i wanted to change it to relative layout,i remember,it was something wrong with lines like xlmns:tools etc. I've copy those lines from my previous app,but then i've got an error that something is missing,so i google it,and somebody wrote about delete .idea and .gradle folders so i did,and now,my avd showing me "old content" just app before some changes. How i can solve it? The application that i've trying to make,it's just an typical clicker at case of my course. It's about to counting score of two teams. Screen with an issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVa3p.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/reset_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/resetBTN"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:onClick="reset_score"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    />
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/team_a"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/team_a_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/team_a_points"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="56sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/three_points_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_3_points_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addThreePointsA"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/two_points_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_2_points_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoPointsA"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/free_throw_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/free_throw_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addOnePointA"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/team_b"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

    <TextView

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/team_b_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/team_b_score"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="56sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/three_points_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_3_points_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addThreePointsB"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/two_points_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_2_points_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoPointsB"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/free_throw_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/free_throw_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="addOnePointB"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.example.kacper.courtcounter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
int team_a_score = 0;
int team_b_score = 0;

private void display_a_score(int score){
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_points);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

private void display_b_score(int score){
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_points);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void addThreePointsA(View view) {
    team_a_score = team_a_score+3;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);
}

public void addTwoPointsA(View view) {
    team_a_score = team_a_score+2;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);
}

public void addOnePointA(View view) {
    team_a_score = team_a_score+1;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);
}


public void addThreePointsB(View view) {
    team_b_score = team_b_score+3;
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

public void addTwoPointsB(View view) {
    team_b_score = team_b_score+2;
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

public void addOnePointB(View view) {
    team_b_score = team_b_score+1;
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

public void reset_score(View view) {
    team_a_score = 0;
    team_b_score = 0;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `Clean` and `rebuild` your project and then **uninstall app from device** and then run again in device it will works fine (If you really make changes in code)